# Is there a way to destructure and access the middle elements?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

On a React component I have a form that, when submitted, calls the following function, where I want to extract the data from the form:

```
const onSubmitFormData = (event) => {
    // 1. Manual way
    const formData = {
        name: event.target.name.value,
        email: event.target.email.value,
        password: event.target.password.value,
        }

    // 2. Automated way??
    const {name: {value}, email, password} = event.target.${}.value;

        //...
    }
```

What I wanted was to use destructuring to get the values from the ids on the form. The problem is that, **for each id, I have to get *id.value***. And if there were 1000 fields on the form, it would be tedious and error prone to write the code as in the manual way...ofc I'm assuming there would be someone willing to fill that 1000-field form!

Jokes aside, is there a way to do this with destructuring or any similar way?

Comment: I don't think there's a shortcut for this. You can write a loop to do it.

Comment: In your form you don't have onChange? You want it only on submit?

Comment: You do have a point @Shivaraj , I could have indeed, along with a state for each field! But then again, if there's 1000 fields, it's 1000 states, it becomes cumbersome. I'd rather just use the onSubmit.

Comment: @jsantos42: You dont need state for each field. You will have just one object and you update the state of the object for that one filed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it just by adding one line of code that:

1. Generates an array of elements with `Object.values(form)`
2. `map` each element to => `[key, value]`

   - So for element `el` it's `el => [el.name, el.value]`
3. Creates an object from that array with `Object.fromEntries()`

If the variable `form` references the form element then the line is:

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.values(form).map(el => [el.name, el.value]))
```

Then destructure away!

```js
function logValues(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const form = e.target
  const formData = Object.fromEntries(Object.values(form).map(el => [el.name, el.value]))
  const {name, email, password} = formData 
  
  console.log(`
    Name: ${name}
    Email: ${email}
    Password: ${password}`)
}
```

```html
<form id="test" onsubmit={logValues(event)}>
  <input name="name" placeholder="Name">
  <input name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <button>Log Values</button>
</form>
```